# How to update child list with Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data

I have an edit Not page and user can add or remove NotRecipient.

Problem is when I save edited Not object it saves edited NotRecipients as new. What I want to do is when I save Not object check NotRecipients name field to update or add new. Is there any way to do this?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "not")
public class Not implements Serializable{

  @Id
  @Column(name = "not_id")
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
  private String notId;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "not", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private List<NotRecipient> recipients = new ArrayList<>();

  //getters and setters
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "not_reciepent")
public class NotRecipient implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "not_recipient_id")
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
  private String notRecipientId;

  @JsonIgnore
  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "not_id")
  private Not not;

  @Column
  private String name;
  //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: How do you load and save your entities? How are your transactions scoped?